# Customizing Installation screen in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, installation

I am working on app where parent app downloads a child app apk file and install it. But as per the requirements I need to customize the installation screen to a new screen . I think everything is possible in Android ..May be this too.Someone who tried this or know he could do this Please help me? I dont know where to start with ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an AsyncTask to download from your url, here is an example that even has a progress bar: [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

While it's downloading, the UI can do anything you want.

When the download is done, your AsyncTask's onPostExecute() method will be called - perform the next step afterwards from there.